# Is there an attribute I can decorate my functions with that I want exported instead of using Export-ModuleMember?

Tags: powershell, scripting, attributes, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell module (`*.psm1`) that contains something like:

```
# [Hide] # Is there some attribute to exclude?
function Instructions {
    Write-Host "This is a helper function I want hidden"
}

# [Export] # Is there an attribute like this I can use instead of "Export-ModuleMember"?
function foo {
    Instructions # Call Helper Function
    Write-Host "Foo"
}

# [Export] # Is there an attribute like this I can use instead of "Export-ModuleMember"?
function bar {
    Instructions # Call Helper Function
    Write-Host "Bar"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function foo
Export-ModuleMember -Function bar
```

And I only want `foo` and `bar` exposed when doing `Import-Module`.

Is there an attribute I can use to just decorate the various functions or must I scan through the file and create an `Export-ModuleMember` line?

Comment: None that I am aware of. Yet, you can just pass or loop of course for the number of items you want to be exported vs those individual export lines, [as per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-7)

Comment: No, there are no such attributes, but you can simplify things somewhat with a _single_ `Export-ModuleMember` call: `Export-ModuleMember -Function foo, bar`. The alternative is to create a full-fledged module, where the `*.psm1` file is placed in a folder of the same base name, along with an attendant `*.psd1` file (module manifest) in which the exports are declared.

Comment: The full-fledged would be overkill. And @postanote I just noticed I can use wildcards. I can just prefix my functions with `Helper` or something and filter out `Helper*`. That seems easy enough

Comment: The variable/function prefix thing (usually a ProjectID or my initials) is an approach I've done for 4 decades in the industry. Why, because that is how I was taught. East to know what functions are yours, easy to remember for lookups, and disposal. So, just something I've always implemented to keep my things unique from anything else on a target system. I require this as a standard for all my teams as well. So, when I see drops, I don't have to ask who did it or what project the code belonged to or came from on sharing and reuse.

Comment: @postanote the _only_ thing is I have to do `-disablenamechecking` and I _might_ get some flack from PS purists because of the warning, but I think the ease/simplicity of less-skilled users just typing our prefix and letting autocomplete aid them is worth it. I like the idea of possibly including some sort of project notation with it as well.

Comment: [Example 7 in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) is pretty much exactly this.

Comment: Note that the name warning only shows for _exported_ functions, and if you're concerned about the private helper functions getting flagged in Visual Studio Code, a simple workaround is to avoid the use of `-` in the name. @JeroenMostert That's a neat trick; as a tip, in case you weren't aware: while you cannot link directly to individual examples, you can link to the "Examples" section: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#examples The high-level anchors are shown to the right, but some topics also have lower-level anchors

Comment: For getting just the examples only, at least the local help files, I wrote a function in my personal module to just pull them. So, just seeing examples code only: I just type [Get-HelpExamples -CmdletName Export-ModuleMember] or [ghe Export-ModuleMember], though the online stuff is more complete of course.